# How to test es6 default values in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How do you test the given default parameter value in jest?

An example having the module:

```
// calculate.js
module.exports = (a, b = 3) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

Or abit more complicated function module.

```
module.exports = (string, blockSizeInBits = 32) => {
    if (string === undefined) {
        return new Error('String not defined.');
    }

    const pad  = blockSizeInBits - (string.length % blockSizeInBits);
    const result = string + String.fromCharCode(0).repeat(pad - 1) + String.fromCharCode(pad);

    return result;
};
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? Would't a call to your function with only one number argument return that number + 3 ? ie, assert result = input + 3?

Comment: The actual example is just a simple function call but I have a bit of complicated code to test.

Comment: principles are the same though - test expected input produces expected output (both arguments passed), then test with the rest param argument missing and make sure output is whatever `32` will produce.  not sure what the difficulty is

Comment: Well if there is no way to get the default params in jest, I need to change the strategy of the actual code to be able to assert the passed value to the function. thanks

Comment: you don't need to check what exact default parameter is set in the function. you need to check that if not provided function works as if it has explicitly set to 32. it might be set not as default value but as extra `if` inside. unit-testing is not to validate code but behavior.

Comment: @skyboyer thanks for the insight. I'll always remember this "unit-testing is not to validate code but behavior"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each expected result of the test case is specified by us, that is, we have set the expected result in advance, whether the result actually returned by the test code is consistent with the expected result, if it is consistent, the test case passes, otherwise, it fails. There is a problem with the code logic.

Besides, our test data and [test double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) should be as simple as possible, so that we can easily infer the results we expect

E.g.

`calculate.js`:

```js
module.exports = (string, blockSizeInBits = 32) => {
  if (string === undefined) {
    return new Error('String not defined.');
  }

  const pad = blockSizeInBits - (string.length % blockSizeInBits);
  const result = string + String.fromCharCode(0).repeat(pad - 1) + String.fromCharCode(pad);
  
  return result;
};
```

`calculate.test.js`:

```js
const calc = require('./calculate');

describe('57941350', () => {
  it('should return an error if string is undefined', () => {
    const actual = calc(undefined);
    expect(actual).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
    expect(actual.message).toBe('String not defined.');
  });
  it('should calculate the result with default block size in bits', () => {
    const testString = 'a'.repeat(32);
    const actual = calc(testString);
    expect(actual).toEqual(testString + '\u0000'.repeat(31) + ' ');
  });
  it('should calculate the result with passed block size in bits', () => {
    const testString = 'a';
    const actual = calc(testString, 1);
    expect(actual).toEqual('a\u0001');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/57941350/calculate.test.js
  57941350
    ✓ should return an error if string is undefined (1 ms)
    ✓ should calculate the result with default block size in bits (1 ms)
    ✓ should calculate the result with passed block size in bits

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 calculate.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.849 s
```

Comment: Wow it took 1 year and 3 months for the answer. Thanks!